# XMPP Server-to-Server for Gmail.com/Jabber.org

Tags: certificate, xmpp, ssl, server-to-server

I'm in the phase of implementing the server-to-server communication part of a XMPP Server.

I'm testing my implementation with Gmail.com and Jabber.org but both seem to use the dialback protocol. Does anyone know more information about this protocol related to this servers?

The protocol seems to be separated in several federation types, and can't seem to find the one this servers use, and the implications of this (root certificate, self-signed certificate, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XEP-220](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0220.html) specifies the dialback protocol.

Keep in mind in your implementation that you may get asked for dialback on a socket that has already been fully set up and had traffic come across it.